# dnx web throws error when try to run from visual studio code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx, visual-studio-code

dnx web command throws error and browser instance is not getting started automatically.

```
C:\Users\Selva\TheYomen>dnx web
Hosting environment: Production
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[3088:1112/112749:WARNING:browser_accessibility_manager_win.cc(193)] Not firing AX event because of no root_delegate or hwnd
[3088:1112/113031:WARNING:browser_accessibility_manager_win.cc(193)] Not firing AX event because of no root_delegate or hwnd
```

Comment: not sure why i am getting negative marks for this post? please don't demotivate beginners :(

Comment: Have an upvote!  The warning doesn't look fatal.  I don't know if visual studio code will launch a browser automatically. What happens if you simply open localhost:5000 on a web browser you launched yourself?

Comment: It works. I have to open the browser manually. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`dnx` will only launch your application in the context of the folder you are in.

That folder must contain a `project.json` which will have the basic commands inside of it. In fact, `dnx web` does not exist in the context of DNX itself but only as a command inside your `project.json`.

`dnx web` basically mean :

> DNX, please launch the `web` command inside the `project.json` inside the folder I am currently in.

DNX does not know whether it is a web application or a console application. Only that it must run the command itself.

Launching a browser would go beyond the bounds of the runtime. It is therefor up to you to launch the browser. The reason VS2015 does it, is because VS knows more about the project you have open than DNX.